# How to map class to database table?

Tags: c#, database, database-design

I'm have classes and need to make data tables  as follow 
Class 1

```
   public class EventType
   { 
        public String Id { get; private set; }
        public int Severity { get; set; }
        public EventTypeTemplate Template { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<String, String> Params { get; set; }
        public EventType(string id)
        { 
            Id = id;
            Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
   }
```

And second class

```
public class EventTypeTemplate
{
     public String Id { get; private set; }
     public int Severity { get; set; }
     public String Title { get; set; }
     public String Description { get; set; }
     public IList<String> Categories { get; private set; }
     public IList<String> Queries { get; private set; }
     public EventTypeTemplate(string id)
     { 
          Id = id;Categories = new List<string>();
          Queries = new List<string>();
     } 
}
```

For class 1(EventType) I create the table
As table name EventType

```
Column    type
Id        string
Severity  int
```

And  I don’t know how to enterprate these  property into table column name and type

```
public EventTypeTemplate Template { get; set; }
public IDictionary<String, String> Params { get; set; }
```

for second class 
I create table name EventTypeTemplate

```
Column          Type
Id              string
Severity        int
Title           string
Description     string
```

But I don’t know how to enterprate follow property into table column name and type

```
public IList<String> Categories { get; private set; }
public IList<String> Queries { get; private set; }
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Template`, in the `EventType` table, add a foreign key to the `EventTypeTemplate` (*EventTypeTemplateId*):

```
EventType
---------
Column              Type
Id                  string
Severity            int
EventTypeTemplateId int
```

For `Params` create a `Params` table with three columns:

```
Params
------
Column       Type
EventTypeId  string
Key          string
Value        string
```

For `Categories` create a table called `Categories`:

```
Categories
----------
EventTypeTemplateId string
CategoryName        string
```

For `Queries` create a table called `Queries`:

```
Queries
----------
EventTypeTemplateId string
Query               string
```

Comment: maark I'm sorry there was typo in question original question is as follow hope you will answer to it

Comment: it doesn't change my suggestion but do you mean `public EventTypeTemplate Template` or is it supposed to be `public categorytocheck Template` ?

Comment: it's   public EventTypeTemplate Template { get; set; }

Comment: please also let me know what type  it should be        EventTypeTemplate is class how to use this

Comment: public EventTypeTemplate Template { get; set; }
how to use this one

Comment: You get the EventTypeTemplate from the query "SELECT * FROM EventTypeTemplate WHERE Id = "+this.eventTypeTemplateId"—you have to store the template ID as a private field (or load the template in the constructor).

Comment: can you get me every thing once again with changes I'm confuse thanks

Comment: how can we define relationship

Comment: EventType to EventTypeTemplate  because EventType.EventTypeTemplateId is int and EventTypeTemplate.Id is string

Comment: and Param.EventTypeId is int and EventType.ID is string

Comment: I corrected it. EventType.EventTypeTemplateId  and Param.EventTypeId  are now strings.